# Brighten images from dark to light on hover

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a script of some sort that will select all images on a page within a certain div.class, apply a transparent black shadowing to it, and then fade it out on hover. Does anyone know of a system of doing this? I can't really modify the site itself (http://cargocollective.com/maureengriswold) or I'd have figured out some shoddy way of doing it already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you would do this by putting a black background behind your images and the set the opacity of the images to some value < 1.

On your site, you would add the following CSS:

```
.cardimgcrop {
    background-color: black;
    border-color: white;
}

.cardimgcrop img {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.cardimgcrop img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want an animated fading, you would leave out the `:hover` CSS definition and add the following Javascript lines (using jQuery 1.4.2 as already used on your site):

```
$(document).delegate('.cardimgcrop img', 'mouseover', function() {
   $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
});
$(document).delegate('.cardimgcrop img', 'mouseout', function() {
   $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.7);
});
```

Of course you could also native CSS transitions instead for this effect (as suggested in [Howard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9057531/170132)), but you would need to take care of browser capabilities.

Comment: Perfect, this works quite well. Didn't think of using opacity. Upvotes for both of you.

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely sure what you mean by transparent black shadowing, but I think you mean an effect like a veil over it, which lifts on hover and returns on mouseout?

You can probably achieve this effect entirely using css. Something like this:

```
DIV.myClass{
  -moz-transition-property: background-color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
DIV.myClass:hover{
  -moz-transition-property: background-color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
```

You'll want to play around with the exact CSS to achieve the effect you want, and also you'll want to test in various browsers as CSS transition support is not 100%.

You can read more on [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions) at the MDN documentation site.

Comment: Note: no need to use `-moz-transition` anymore, Firefox now supports just `transition`, which also works in Chrome 26+, IE10+ and Opera. Safari and Chrome 25- though still require `-webkit-transition`.

Answer (score 0):

CSS filters are another option http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html